# Sending private messages to facebook accounts using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rubygems

I need to make the user able to send private message to his friends through facebook. In PHP there is something called Openinviter which can grab the contacts of nearly any social network or email provider.

I found a gem on rails called contacts that does the same thing for email providers. It can grab users friends from email providers but not social networks.

Is there a similar gem or plugin that I could use to make my application send private messages to facebook contacts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sending private messages via email you've fetched from facebook's API or from a facebook app via the API seems to be against the current API TOS/Policies has in effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Facebook Chat API to send private messages, here is an example in Ruby using xmpp4r_facebook gem:

```
sender_chat_id = "-#{sender_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
receiver_chat_id = "-#{receiver_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
message_body = "message body"
message_subject = "message subject"

jabber_message = Jabber::Message.new(receiver_chat_id, message_body)
jabber_message.subject = message_subject

client = Jabber::Client.new(Jabber::JID.new(sender_chat_id))
client.connect
client.auth_sasl(Jabber::SASL::XFacebookPlatform.new(client,
   ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'), facebook_auth.token,
   ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET')), nil)
client.send(jabber_message)
client.close
```